# Can I have a package.json but avoid my project from getting published to npm servers?

Tags: node.js, npm

Basically the thing is I'm working on a project that uses `grunt` for build tasks and as I have a few dependencies here and there I thought it was a good idea to declare those on a `package.json` so that my co-workers can `npm install` without being required to manually install every package at the correct version.

Now the thing is, what if someone "accidentally" runs `npm publish`? Is there a way to have the `package.json` while keeping my stuff private?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[Yes, set `private` to `true`.](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#private)

> If you set `"private": true` in your package.json, then npm will refuse
>   to publish it.
>
> This is a way to prevent accidental publication of private
>   repositories. If you would like to ensure that a given package is only
>   ever published to a specific registry (for example, an internal
>   registry), then use the publishConfig hash described below to override
>   the registry config param at publish-time.

Comment: awesome, I was sure I looked around for this and didn't see anything related. thanks both to you and @pfried.

Answer (score 9):

You can set `"private" : true` in your package.json file

Your CoWorkers will get an error if they try to publish it